# How can i set woocommerce global attribute for 100 products by sql?

Tags: wordpress, attributes, woocommerce

I uploaded more than 1000 products to woocommerce. I created global attribute with 3 options (ex1,ex2,ex3). I want to update latest 100 products with pa_manufacturer=ex1 by SQL.

I think, here is code which selects attribute.

```
SELECT t.*, tt.*
FROM wp_terms AS t
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr
ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('pa_manufacturer')
AND tr.object_id IN (13860)
ORDER BY t.name ASC;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please post what you tried till now

Comment: Currently, I want to know how stored attribute data.